# Help with high-school investigation/experiment on astrophysics

Tags: experimental-physics, astrophysics, education, stars

I need to find multiple ideas for a physics investigation relating to astrophysics. The investigation is going to be like a lab report and must include data analysis and be maximum 2000 words. I have already thought of one idea: Investigating the relationship between the size and the position on the Hertzsprung-Russel diagram of stars.

Do you know other variables that I could substitute for "size" in the previous research question? -that would have a relationship with the position of stars on the H-R diagram? Or do you know any laws or other topics in astrophysics that I could investigate?

Let me know what you think!

Comment: You could retrace Edwin Hubble's steps: check the correlation between red shift and distance from Earth and investigate its implications for the universe. You can find the necessary data online (or you could measure the red shift yourself).